# Showing that a tensor product of fields is equal to a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

How do I show that ${\bf Q}(2^{1/3}) \otimes_{\bf Q} {\bf Q}(\sqrt{2}) = {\bf Q}(2^{1/3}, \sqrt{2})$? I know that $1 \otimes 1, 1 \otimes \sqrt{2}, 2^{1/3} \otimes 1, 2^{2/3} \otimes 1, 2^{1/3} \otimes \sqrt{2}, 2^{2/3} \otimes \sqrt{2}$ is a basis.

Comment: Just a nitpick: Be careful with "equal." It is surprisingly ambiguous word. I think you probably want to show that they are *isomorphic* fields.

Answer (score 11):

The buzzword here is "linearly disjoint".

Let $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ and $L=\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$. There is a ring homomorphism
 $K\otimes L\to\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,2^{1/3})=\Bbb Q(2^{1/6})$
satisfying $a\otimes b\mapsto ab$. Both sides are six-dimensional
and you have written down a basis of $K\otimes L$. To show this map
is an isomorphism, all you have to do is to show this basis maps
to a basis of $\Bbb Q(2^{1/6})$.

ADDED IN EDIT

Field extensions $K/F$ and $L/F$ are *linearly disjoint* whenever
$K\otimes_F L$ is a field. When the degrees of the field extensions are coprime (as in this example) the extensions are automatically linear disjoint.